# Parse Server : user information cannot be changed on cloud code

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, parse-platform, ionic4

I want to change user information in the cloud but information does not change on the cloud

index.js

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/meet2me',
  cloud:  __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: 'app',
  masterKey: 'burak21', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

Main.js

```
Parse.Cloud.define('changeSearchStatus', async (request) => {

      //Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
      var search_yn = request.params.search_yn == true ? '1' : '0';
      var only_gold_write = request.params.only_gold_write == true ? '1' : '0';
      var only_gold_call = request.params.only_gold_call == true ? '1' : '0';
      var min_age = request.params.min_age;
      var max_age = request.params.max_age;

      var query = new Parse.Query("User");
      query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.token);

      var out_data = {
          error:"0",
          mesaj:'success'
      };

      query.first({ useMasterKey: true },{
          success: function (user) {
              console.log("USERBILGI : "+user.get("email"));
              user.set("search_yn", search_yn);
              user.set("only_gold_write", only_gold_write);
              user.set("only_gold_call", only_gold_call);
              user.set("age_lower", min_age);
              user.set("age_upper", max_age);
              user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
          }, error: function (error) {
            var out_data = {
                error:"1",
                mesaj:'Fail'
            };
            console.log("error  HATA");
          }
      });

  return out_data;

});
```

İonic Code

```
async  changeSearchStatus(){
    console.log("gelen:"+this.rangedualKnobs+" : "+this.rangedualKnobs['lower']);
       var body = {
         useMasterKey: true,
         token:this.apiService.getToken(),
         search_yn:this.search_yn,
         only_gold_write:this.only_gold_write,
         only_gold_call:this.only_gold_call,
         min_age:this.rangedualKnobs['lower'],
         max_age:this.rangedualKnobs['upper']
       };
       const response = await Parse.Cloud.run("changeSearchStatus", body);

  }
```

Console Output :

info: Ran cloud function changeSearchStatus for user undefined with:
  Input: {"useMasterKey":true,"token":"X38ZMM2At9","search_yn":1,"only_gold_write":true,"only_gold_call":false,"min_age":"18","max_age":"55"}
  Result: {"error":"0","mesaj":"success"} {"functionName":"changeSearchStatus","params":{"useMasterKey":true,"token":"X38ZMM2At9","search_yn":1,"only_gold_write":true,"only_gold_call":false,"min_age":"18","max_age":"55"}}

it does not give an error but the user information does not change

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for your cloud code:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('changeSearchStatus', async (request) => {

    //Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var search_yn = request.params.search_yn == true ? '1' : '0';
    var only_gold_write = request.params.only_gold_write == true ? '1' : '0';
    var only_gold_call = request.params.only_gold_call == true ? '1' : '0';
    var min_age = request.params.min_age;
    var max_age = request.params.max_age;

    var query = new Parse.Query("User");
    query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.token);

    var out_data = {
        error:"0",
        mesaj:'success'
    };

    try {
        const user = await query.first({ useMasterKey: true });

        console.log("USERBILGI : "+user.get("email"));
        user.set("search_yn", search_yn);
        user.set("only_gold_write", only_gold_write);
        user.set("only_gold_call", only_gold_call);
        user.set("age_lower", min_age);
        user.set("age_upper", max_age);
        await user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    } catch (e) {
        var out_data = {
            error:"1",
            mesaj:'Fail'
        };
        console.log("error  HATA");
    }

    return out_data;

});
```